# python BeautifulSoup returns extra content

Tags: python, parsing, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a kickstarter pledge amount tracker that updates printed amount without printing another line.

The issue I am having is that it prints additional characters along with the  pledge dollar amount.

I think this has something to do with indenting, but I am not sure.

Here is what is prints:

```
(u'\n$116,954\n,)
```

It should instead say:

```
$116,954
```

With updating to same print without adding a new line.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time  
amount = ''
url = raw_input("What is the URL?")
def pageCrawler():
    global amount
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'
    }
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "green-700 inline-block js-usd_pledged medium type-16 type-24-md"})
    result = data[0].text
    if amount != result :
        amount = result
        print(amount,)
        time.sleep(1)


while 1:
    pageCrawler()
    time.sleep(10)  #check amount every 10 seconds
```

I removed the notification tone and (int converting) menu to select kickstarter, youtube, or instructables options from this code here for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Perhaps that part contains a line break before and after that amount. Why can't you to `result = data[0].text.strip()`?

Comment: That's a Unicode string. Decode it, and it should be normal.

Comment: I tried decoding using unidecode and also .strip()  No improvement.  `from unidecode import unidecode
 result = unidecode(result)
 result = result.strip('')`

Comment: Ok. so, removing the comma in `print(amount,)` fixes the extra character issue.  However, now it does not update the existing printed line. It instead just prints to a newline when new it updates.  How can I fix this?

Comment: `print(chr(27) + "[2J")` just before your print statement will clear the terminal (for most terminals). Source: stackoverflow.com/a/208452